# Is it possible to have a variadic argument list for a template or automatically generated specifications based on supplied argument list

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have the following `tuple`:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> setVals(int val)
{
   return std::make_tuple(val, val, val);
}
```

It is really nice to have structured bindings with this: `auto [x, y, z] = setVals(42);`

Would it be possible to have some kind of variadic signature for `setVals`, so I could do structured bindings with any number of variables? For instance, `auto [x, y] = setVals(42);` or `auto [x, y, z, x2, y2, z2] = setVals(42);`

I know that I could just use a variadic function template where I could just declare some ints and pass them in as references, but the structured bindings are so convenient that I was wondering if something like I just showed is possible. I'm sorry if this question is bad.

Comment: Not possible without specifying the number of variables in the function call.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat do you mean that there would have to be a parameter in setVals specifying the number of arguments?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::get<i>(tup)`?

Comment: @lorro I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @beangod sorry, I misunderstood - I thought you mean the problem is defining x, y, z...

Comment: @beangod Yep...

Comment: In case you just want to set multiple ints, `operator=` is chainable: `int x = y = z = ...;`

Comment: @beangod: I don't see where this "supplied argument list" is. I see how the return value is used, but that's something that exists outside of the function itself. Structured binding is not an "argument list".

Comment: @lorro You can't do a declaration like that,  You'd need `int x = 42, y = x, z = y, x1 = z ... ;`

Comment: @NathanOliver What I meant, `int x, y, z; x = y = z = ...;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function like what you want but you have to specify the number of elements the tuple will have as a template parameter.  That would give you code like:

```
// does the actual creation
template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto create_tuple_helper(const T& initial_value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    // this ueses the comma expression to discard Is and use initial_value instead for each element
    return std::tuple{(void(Is), initial_value)...};
    // void(Is) is used to get rid of a warning for an unused value
}

// this is a wrapper and makes it easy to call the helper function
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto create_tuple(const T& initial_value)
{
    return create_tuple_helper(initial_value, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main()
{
    auto [a, b, c, d] = create_tuple<4>(42);
    std::cout << d;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dd9d5b064788d96)

Comment: Nice one! Using template lambda, the wrapper would be enough: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6szvM9zn8